# Core Data save successful, but no data in database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I've been working on adding Core Data into my iPhone app, and I've been running into some very frustrating issues. When I call save on my context, the save returns successfully, however no data is getting added to my database(I am running this on the simulator and looking at the SQLITE file to check).

I am using the `MYDocumentHandler` class from [this post](http://adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html) to use a single `UIManagedDocument` across multiple classes. I run the code in my `AppDelegate` as follows:

```
if (!self.document) {
    [[MYDocumentHandler sharedDocumentHandler] performWithDocument:^(UIManagedDocument *document) {
        self.document = document;
        self.context = document.managedObjectContext;
        [self loadView];
    }];
}
```

The `loadView` method setups up my view controllers once the document has been returned. In my view controllers that use the Core Data I again use something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(!self.document){
        [[MYDocumentHandler sharedDocumentHandler] performWithDocument:^(UIManagedDocument *document) {
            self.document = document;
            self.context = document.managedObjectContext;
            [self loadAll];
        }];
    }


}
```

Where the `loadAll` method setups everything for the view. When I try to save my data, I use the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [jsonArray count]; i++) {
                    NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    ProjectObject *tempProject = [[ProjectObject alloc] initWithDict:dictionary andETag:etag];
                    [tempAllProjects addObject:[Projects newProject:tempProject withContext:self.context]];
                    [tempProject release];
                }


                [self saveWithContext:self.context];
```

My `saveWithContext` method looks like this:

```
- (BOOL) saveWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (context != nil) {
        if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
            DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } else{
            DLog(@"save was successful");
            return YES;
        }
    }else{
        DLog(@"context is nil");
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I always get the `save was successful` message, and I get the proper messages from the MYDocumentHandler file. Unfortunately, the data is simply not making it to the database. The data is definitely stored in the context, but its not going to the database. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
Here is the code where I create the Entities:

```
+ (Projects *) newProject:(ProjectObject *)project withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Projects *newProject = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Projects"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"project_id = %@", project.project_id];
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if([results count] > 0){
        newProject = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        newProject.account_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"account_id"]];

    } else {
        newProject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Projects" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }

    newProject.account_id = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"account_id"]];
    newProject.project_id = project.project_id;
    newProject.name = project.name;
    newProject.project_description = project.description;
    newProject.updated_at = project.updated_at;
    newProject.starred = project.starred;
    newProject.etag = project.etag;

    newProject.synced = [self hasConnection] ? [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    return newProject;
}
```

Comment: Could it simply be that your data is not getting added? If you set a breakpoint in saveWithContext, does `[context hasChanged]` return true?

Comment: hmmm. You're right. The context hasn't changed. Any way to rectify that?

Comment: If you show the code where you create your new entities you might be able to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609225/saved-core-data-does-not-persist-after-app-closes-80-of-the-time) post. Not sure if this is the best way to handle it. If there is a better option, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving Manage object context after changing it. I have added the lines into your code.
 Please check if it works now.